# GnuPlot how do I plot a wireframe surface with uneven grid data

Tags: microsoft-surface, gnuplot, grid

I am trying to plot a set of grid data with specific axis values where the y-axis is uneven (eg ... 150 180 195). Believe it or not, it's the deformation in an concrete ceiling that I want to level with the least amount of plaster...! The grid values are as follows.
[Grid data with x & y axis data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGMlV.png)

I have tried the macro below but with very indifferent results-:

[Macro attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEO4S.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need the keyword `nonuniform` :

```
gnuplot> help matrix

(...) 

The second interpretation assumes a non-uniform grid with explicit x and y
 coordinates. The first row of input data contains the y coordinates; 
 the first column of input data contains the x coordinates.  For binary input
 data, the first element of the first row must contain the number of columns.
 This is the default for `binary matrix` input, but requires an additional
 keyword `nonuniform` for text input data.
 See `matrix nonuniform` for examples.
```